# What does colon mean when importing core libraries in Dart?

Tags: dart

What does *colon* mean when importing core libraries in Dart?

```
import 'dart:math';
```

I haven't find any resources that tells what does that mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart imports are specified using a [URI](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), or a relative URI reference.

URIs have a *scheme*, which come before the first `:`. The scheme defines how to interpret the part that comes after the `:`.

The import `import 'dart:html';` uses a URI with the scheme `dart` and the scheme-specific resource identifier `html`. The `dart` scheme is used to access platform libraries, so `dart:html` is the platform HTML library.

An import like `import 'package:test/test.dart';` uses the `package` scheme, which is another Dart-specific scheme. The scheme is followed by a package name (`test`) and a path, `/test.dart`, which refers to a file inside that package.

An import like `import 'file:///home/myself/src/dart/mypkg/bin/main.dart`;`used the`file` scheme to point to a file on the local machine.

An import like `import 'src/helper.dart';` uses a *relative* URI reference, which has no scheme, but which is resolved against the URI of the containing library to create a complete URI.

In the first three cases, the `colon` is the URI scheme separator. The schemes `dart` and `package` are specific to Dart tools, and `file` is a general URI scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You should use colon when you try to import other packages modules...
You can omit it when the module that you are importing is in the same package.

```
import '<package>:<module>'; // normal import
/* 
  if the module is the in the same package of the file where i'm importing it 
*/
import '<module>';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility) (emphasis mine):

**Using libraries**

Use import to specify how a namespace from one library is used in the scope of another library.

For example, Dart web apps generally use the `dart:html` library, which they can import like this:

`import 'dart:html';`

The only required argument to `import` is a URI specifying the library. For built-in libraries, the URI has the special `dart:` scheme. For other libraries, you can use a file system path or the `package:` scheme. The `package:` scheme specifies libraries provided by a package manager such as the pub tool. For example:

`import 'package:test/test.dart';`

> Note: URI stands for uniform
> resource identifier. URLs (uniform resource locators) are a common
> kind of URI.